# If FullCalendar 4 shows events only for current month error when loading data from datesRender event?

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In my Laravel 8 / jQuery 3.5.1 / bootstrap  4.5.3 app with FullCalendar v4.3.1 I show events only for current month and user can select month by clicking on Next Prior month arrows  of the calendar.

I need to retrieve data from db only for selected month. I need to run data retrieve method when user clicks on Next Prior month arrows. I make it with datesRender event, but I got problems that datesRender is triggered again when data retrieved and I got endless triggering of this method.

I do :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    adExpireDateEvenstLoadWithFullCalendar()  // get data from db for selected month
    ...
}) // jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

function adExpireDateEvenstLoadWithFullCalendar () { // get data from db for selected month
    var dataArray = {
        '_token': '{{ $csrf_token }}',
        'year': select_year,
        'month': parseInt(select_month) + 1
    }

    var href = "/admin/get_ad_events"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: href,
        data: dataArray,
        success: function (response) {
            initFullCalendar(response.events, response.calendar_events_default_date);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            popupErrorMessage(error.responseJSON.message)
        }
    });

} // function adExpireDateEvenstLoadWithFullCalendar () { // get data from db for selected month

function initFullCalendar(eventsList, calendar_events_default_date) { // init FullCalendar with given array of data and month
    if (typeof window.calendarEventsObject != "undefined") { // clear existing instance
        window.calendarEventsObject.destroy();
    }

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('expire_date_events_calendar');

    var current_date = moment(calendar_events_default_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    var today = moment();

    window.calendarEventsObject = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { // FullCalendar Init
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',

        views: {
            dayGridMonth: {
                buttonText: 'Month'
            },
            timeGridWeek: {
                buttonText: 'Week'
            }
        },


        axisFormat: "H:mm A",
        timeFormat: "H:mm A",

        header: {
            left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'today prev,next '
        },

        eventRender: function (eventInfo) {
            ...
        }, // eventRender: function (eventInfo) {


        dayRender: function (date) {
           ...
        },

        datesRender: function (view) {
            select_year= view.view.currentStart.getFullYear()
            select_month= view.view.currentStart.getMonth()
            if (calendarExpireDateEventsObject) {
                calendarExpireDateEventsObject.datepicker('setDate', new Date(select_year, select_month, 1)).trigger('change');
                adExpireDateEvenstLoadWithFullCalendar() // I need to read data for selected month and THIS RAISE endless triggering of this method

            }
        }, // datesRender

        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            ...
        },

        events: eventsList,
        defaultDate: current_date,
        showNonCurrentDates: false,
        displayEventTime: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        selectOverlap: false,
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        disableDragging: true,

        aspectRatio: 0.4,
        height: 900,
        eventClick: function (clickObj) {
            ...
            return false;
        },
    });  // window.calendarEventsObject = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { // FullCalendar Init
    //    'calendar_events_default_date' => '2019-08-22',

    window.calendarEventsObject.render(
        {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            textColor: 'yellow',
        }
    );

    jQuery('.eo-fullcalendar').on('click', '.fc-event', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    });

}   // function initFullCalendar(eventsList, calendar_events_default_date) { // init FullCalendar with given array of data and month
```

Any hints how that  can be fixed ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
I found this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function page
and try to use it in my blade page :

```
@section('scripts')

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/fullcalendar/core/main.css') }}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css') }}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css') }}" type="text/css">

<link href="{{ asset('css/gijgo.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ asset('css/jquery-ui.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="{{ asset('js/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>


<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar/core/main.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar/timegrid/main.js') }}"></script>


<script src="{{ url('js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>

    let select_year = '{{ $select_year }}'
    let select_month = '{{ $select_month }}'
    let calendarExpireDateEventsObject = null
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        backendInit('list', 'expire_date_events_calendar')
        // fullCalendarInit()
        console.log('BEFORE::')
        // import { req } from 'superagent'; // ajax library

        var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

            events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {

                req.get('myxmlfeed.php')
                    .type('xml')
                    .query({
                        start: info.start.valueOf(),
                        end: info.end.valueOf()
                    })
                    .end(function(err, res) {

                        if (err) {
                            failureCallback(err);
                        } else {

                            successCallback(
                                Array.prototype.slice.call( // convert to array
                                    res.getElementsByTagName('event')
                                ).map(function(eventEl) {
                                    return {
                                        title: eventEl.getAttribute('title'),
                                        start: eventEl.getAttribute('start')
                                    }
                                })
                            )
                        }
                    })

            }

        });
```

and I got error in the console :

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Maybe I missed some .js files     ?
included list of files worked ok for my priorcode...
All files v4.3.0.

Thanks!

Comment: `I need to run data retrieve method when user clicks on Next Prior month arrows`...no, you don't. You need to follow the proper system for doing this which fullCalendar has provided. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function . If you give fullCalendar a callback function which runs your AJAX request, it will automatically call that function whenever it needs new events (i.e. whenever the date range being displayed changes). It passes the current start/end dates into the function so that you can use them in your AJAX to send to the server. No need to mess with datesRender etc.

Comment: Could you, please, give a link to working example  with AJAX request and event-function.?V4

Comment: Why? what did you try? what went wrong? what specifically didn't you understand from the documentation? We're not really here to Google for tutorials and examples on your behalf, if I'm honest. Explain a specific problem when you attempted to implement the idea, and then we can answer it here with an example specific to your scenario which addresses your particular issues/concerns.

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Well that's you just blindly copying the example from the docs. Obviously your real feed doesn't download XML. Replace that bit with _your_ ajax call, and pass _your_ event results to the successCallback. And the whole thing needs to replace `events: eventsList` within _your existing calendar configuration_. Did you not really understand the concept, or did you just not spend any time on it?

Comment: Maybe i am blind, but error shows at var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl,  line, before any call to successCallback.

Comment: Yes. Because as I already mentioned, the events function needs to go inisde _your existing calendar configuration_ to replace `events: eventsList` . You seem to be attempting to create a whole new calendar, which does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> I need to run data retrieve method when user clicks on Next Prior
> month arrows

...but actually no, you don't. You need to follow the proper system for doing this which fullCalendar has provided. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function . If you give fullCalendar a callback function which runs your AJAX request, it will automatically call that function whenever it needs new events (i.e. whenever the date range being displayed changes). It passes the current start/end dates into the function so that you can use them in your AJAX to send to the server. No need to mess with datesRender etc.

You seem to be having some trouble relating the documentation to your own code, so here is an example of how you should do it. Obviously I haven't tested this, but this should give you the right idea.

Also, currently you are sending month and year to your server, but fullCalendar will pass you specific start and end dates. You should send these to your server. Then you should modify the server code so that it returns all events within these start and end dates, rather than for a specific months. This is because if, for example, you are using the "week" view instead of the "month" view, the dates that fullCalendar sends will cover 1 week instead of 1 month. So you need a bit more flexibility than just returning a whole month of events.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    loadCalendar();  //initialise the calendar
})

function loadCalendar() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('expire_date_events_calendar');
    window.calendarEventsObject = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { // FullCalendar Init
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        views: {
            dayGridMonth: {
                buttonText: 'Month'
            },
            timeGridWeek: {
                buttonText: 'Week'
            }
        },
        axisFormat: "H:mm A",
        timeFormat: "H:mm A",
        header: {
            left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'today prev,next '
        },
        eventRender: function (info) {
            //...
        },
        dayRender: function (dayRenderInfo) {
           //...
        },
        select: function (selectionInfo) {
            //...
        },
        events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {    //get data from db for selected dates
          var dataArray = {
            '_token': '{{ $csrf_token }}',
            'start': info.startStr,
            'end': info.endStr
          }
          var href = "/admin/get_ad_events";
    
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: href,
              data: dataArray,
              success: function (response) {
                  successCallback(response.events);
              },
              error: function (error) {
                  failureCallback(error);
                  popupErrorMessage(error.responseJSON.message);
              }
          });
        },
        showNonCurrentDates: false,
        displayEventTime: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        selectOverlap: false,
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        disableDragging: true,
        aspectRatio: 0.4,
        height: 900,
        eventClick: function (eventClickInfo) {
            //...
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```